# how to construct block diagonal matrix

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen3

In Matlab, this function `blkdiag` construct block diagonal matrix. For example, if I have

```
a = [ 2,     2;
      2,     2]
```

Then `blkdiag(a,a)` will return this output

```
>> blkdiag(a,a)

ans =

     2     2     0     0
     2     2     0     0
     0     0     2     2
     0     0     2     2
```

Is there an alternative in Eigen Library for `blkdiag`? The size of the big matrix varies which means classical approaches won't work. I mean to directly construct a matrix like the aforementioned output.

Comment: You should make a little less specific example. Because for this I would make a function that glues two constant square matrices. Can the arguments be totally general in size and contents, or always the same matrix with the same value inside?

Comment: Yes the size of the submatrix is fixed. I can do a function to achieve the above output but the problem is that the size of the big matrix varies depending on how many submatrices are intended to be fused in the big matrix.

Answer (score 1):

A simple function like

```
MatrixXd blkdiag(const MatrixXd& a, int count)
{
    MatrixXd bdm = MatrixXd::Zero(a.rows() * count, a.cols() * count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        bdm.block(i * a.rows(), i * a.cols(), a.rows(), a.cols()) = a;
    }

    return bdm;
}
```

does the job.

If the argument sub-matrix a can be fixed-size or dynamic-size or an expression then the following is a better choice

```
template <typename Derived>
MatrixXd blkdiag(const MatrixBase<Derived>& a, int count)
{
    MatrixXd bdm = MatrixXd::Zero(a.rows() * count, a.cols() * count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        bdm.block(i * a.rows(), i * a.cols(), a.rows(), a.cols()) = a;
    }

    return bdm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is already solved! Just see the eigen documentation for topleftcorner and bottomrightcorner in http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a6f5fc5fe9d3fb70e62d4a9b1795704a8 and http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a2b9618f3c9eb4d4c9813ae8f6a8e70c5 respectively.

All you have to do is assign a matrix to those places, more or less like this:

//Assuming `A` is the result and has the right size allocated with zeroes, and `a` is the matrix you have.

```
A.topLeftCorner(a.rows(),a.cols())=a;
```

same for bottom right corner, unless you want to flip matrix (try methods `.reverse()` and `.transpose()` to get the desired flip effect) `a` before copying it there.

You can also try the `.block()` function for better handling of the matrices.